# Why does a centrifuge cause blood to be pushed downwards in the human body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, centrifugal-force, biophysics

Good evening all, 

I recently watched this YouTube video about a centrifuge by Tom Scott
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMKcO-T5Y4o). Around the 2:30 mark, it is said that blood will be 'pushed down' towards his feet as the g-force increases. I'm pretty sure that I have also heard this from other sources as well.

As I understand it, g-force is a measure of acceleration, where acceleration is expressed as a multiple of $g=9.8ms^{-2}$. However, since the person in the centrifuge travels in a circle, surely this acceleration is in the radial direction (i.e. horizontal)? Therefore, I am wondering how the g-force causes blood to be pushed in the downwards direction? Is it because the g-force causes the person to feel heavier? Also, does the downward acceleration of 1g towards the earth that the person experiences due to gravity factor into this calculation for g-force?

Comment: The bucket swings so that it's easy to get into while allowing the sum of gravity and the rotational acceleration to act directly downward. ("*[You are basically put into a small coffin. It swings a little as you enter](https://sofrep.com/fightersweep/the-centrifuge-what-its-like-to-pull-gs/)...*")

Comment: his body's downward is the centrifuge's outward because of how he's oriented in the centrifuge

Comment: ...in other words, When they say "down," they don't mean, "toward the center of the Earth." They mean, "toward the subject's feet."

Comment: So does this mean that the person is tilted to be horizontal, with their head closer to the centre and feet further away? @SolomonSlow

Comment: Yes. Watch the video closely. It's what Chemomecanics said above, the seat and the cage surrounding it swing on a pivot so that the subject always feels like "down" is toward the seat and their feet.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. Does that then mean that there is a centripetal (normal) force keeping the person travelling in a circle, and a centrifugal force which acts to push the blood towards the person's feet (in the direction of outwards from the centre of the circle)? Surely gravity would still act perpendicularly to these forces though (i.e. downwards towards the earth)? @SolomonSlow

Comment: Thanks very much everyone for your helpful answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that then mean that there is a centripetal (normal) force keeping the person travelling in a circle, and a centrifugal force...

The words, "centripetal" and "centrifugal" belong to different realms.

We say, "centripetal" when we describe the *motion* of the subject as they follow a circular path in an [inertial (non-rotatating) coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference). Centripetal force provides the acceleration needed to keep the subject traveling on the circular path. It arises because the subject's inertia wants them to fly off in a straight line, tangent to the circle, but the rigid structure of the seat and the cage and the spinning arm all "get in the way," *forcing* the subject to stay on the circular path.

We say, "centrifugal" when we are trying to describe the subject's experience. From their point of view, they are *stationary* in their seat, and everything around them experiences a force that tends to pull stuff away from the hub of the centrifuge. When we talk about "centrifugal" force, we don't try to explain it. We just call it a [*fictitious force*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force) (a.k.a., "pseudo force"). If we want a physical explanation for the force, we always take the outside observer's non-rotating, inertial point of view. (I.e., we switch to talking about "centripetal" force instead.)

---

> ...which acts to push the blood towards the person's feet (in the direction of outwards from the centre of the circle)?

In the "centripetal" point of view, the blood is not pushed toward the subject's feet. The subject's *feet* are pushed (by the floor of the cage) toward the blood. The hub of the rotor pulls on the spinning arm, the arm pulls on the top of the cage, the cage pulls on the floor, and the floor pushes up on the subject. The subject's feet are pushed up against their blood and leg bones. The rest of their body is pushed up by the seat, and etc.

In the "centrifugal" point of view we turn it all upside-down. We say that the fictitious centrifugal force is *pulling* the subject's blood and organs and bones "down," and that the subject's increased weight pushes down on the floor, and the floor pulls down on the cage, etc.

---

> Surely gravity would still act perpendicularly to these forces though (i.e. downwards towards the earth)?

Yes. Force is a vector quantity. In the purely "centrifugal" point of view,* the force that they feel is the [vector sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction) of the pure centrifugal force and gravity.

In the modern viewpoint, "gravitational force" also is a fictitious force. According to the theory of relativity, we feel "gravitational force" because our inertia wants us to fall toward the center of the Earth, but the surface of the Earth gets in the way. It pushes *up* against our feet and stops us from falling.

Therefore, in the external observer's "centripetal" view of the experiment, the complete explanation for the motion of the subject involves the vector sum of the centripetal force due to the spinning of the machine, and the force of the Earth pushing up against the floor of the lab, stopping the entire lab from falling toward the Earth's core.

---

* But note!! The subject's point of view is not *purely* the centrifugal point of view because the cage *swings.* The cage always is tilted just so that from the subject's point of view, "down" is the same direction as the vector sum of the gravitational force and the centrifugal force.

Comment: Thank you so much, @SolomonSlow, that's a really helpful answer. If I may ask a few questions:
1) You say that "if we want a physical explanation for the force, we always take the outside observer's non-rotating, inertial point of view". Does this mean that the perspective from the inertial frame is more "valid", or are the perspectives in both the inertial and rotating frames of reference equally correct? 
2) In the "centripetal" point of view, why is the person's blood not also pushed in the same direction due to contact force with the feet?

Comment: 3) Why is the subject's weight "increased" in the "centrifugal" point of view?
4) Why does the fact that the subject is tilted mean that they are not purely in the "centrifugal" point of view?
5) If "gravitational force" is a fictitious force, why do we have that inertia to begin with? In other words, why do we have a tendency to fall towards the centre of the earth if there is no non-fictitious force pulling us in that direction? @SolomonSlow